# Faster stringdist_inner_join

Tags: match, fuzzy

I am trying to match company names from two large databases (4000 and 23000). However, it is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to speed up this process? for example, parallelize this code?. I have been searching here but found nothing relevant yet. I would appreciate any help you could provide. My basic command is:

```
 x <- stringdist_inner_join(tbl.nomatch, tbl.reuters, by ="company",  method="jw")
```

Thank you very much.